# Characterization of a locally finite open cover

Tags: general-topology

This question is in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, on "Bump Functions and Partitions of Unity".

> **Exercise 2.9:** Show that an open cover $\{\mathcal{U_{\alpha}}\}_{\alpha \in A}$ $X$ is locally finite if and only if each $\mathcal{U_{\alpha}}$ intersects $\mathcal{U_{\beta}}$ for only finitely many $\beta$. Give a counterexample
>   if the sets of the cover are not assumed to be open.

I came up with an example that I think contradicts this proposition:

Define $U:=\mathbb{R}\times(0,1)\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and $U_n:= (n, n+1)\times (\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2})\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. If we define $X:=U\cup\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}U_n$, we have that $\{U\}\cup\{U_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is an open cover for $X$ which is locally finite but $U$ intersects $U_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, i.e., infinitely many $n$, which contradicts the "only if" statement.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I agree with you. It seems that this cover is locally finite, but has open sets which intersect infinitely many others. An analogous example could be made out of any infinite but locally finite cover by adding the whole space to the cover (if it's not there already). Maybe Lee didn't mean to include the "only if"? Or maybe the statement can be repaired by passing to a subcover?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such Exercise 2.9, in either the first or the second edition of my *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*. You must be using one of the pirated draft versions of the first edition, which somebody posted illegally on the internet. Those are full of mistakes and come with no guarantees.